# Bash script to install the software

Tags: bash

I have bash script to install the tomcat and java, this will happen based on user selection inputs, this is working good as we expected. when the java and tomcat is not present it will configure one by one as per the below code. if the tomcat and java is already present then it will through the error in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

tomcat_base_dir=/sys/workers
java_base_dir=/usr/lib/java
software_location=/home/softwares/

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
clear

echo "==========================="
echo "Softeare Setup"
echo "==========================="

options=("Option 1: Tomcat Installation" "Option 2: Java Installation" "Option 3: Reply" "Quit")

COLUMNS=12
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $opt in

        "Option 1: Tomcat Installation")
                echo "you chose choice 1"

                echo "Tomcat Installation"
                echo "================================================================"
                if [ ! -d $tomcat_base_dir ]; then
                        echo "Error directory $tomcat_base_dir does not exists!"
                        mkdir -p /sys/workers
                        cp -r $software_location/apache*.gz $tomcat_base_dir
                        echo "tomcat file copied"
                        cd $tomcat_base_dir && tar zxf apache*.gz -C . && rm -rf apache*.gz && mv a* tomcat
                        echo "Tomcat tar file removed and renamed as well"
                        echo "Tomcat Version"
                        tomcat_output="$(cd $tomcat_base_dir/bin && ./version.sh | grep -i "Server version")"
                        echo "============================"
                        echo "${tomcat_output}"
                        echo "============================"
                else
                        echo "$tomcat_base_dir directory found!"
                fi
                ;;

        "Option 2: Java Installation")

                echo "you chocie 2"
                echo "Java Installation"
                echo "================================================================"

                if [ ! -d $java_base_dir ]; then
                        echo "Error directory $java_base_dir does not exists!"
                        mkdir -p /usr/lib/java
                        cp -r $software_location/jre*.gz $java_base_dir
                        echo "java file copied"
                        cd $java_base_dir && tar zxf jre*.gz -C . && rm -rf jre*.gz && mv j* jre
                        sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/java/jre/bin/java" 1
                        sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/java/jre/bin/javaws" 1
                        echo "Java Runtime Environment installtion completed"
                        java_output="$(java -version 2>&1 | head -n 1 | cut -d\" -f 2)"
                        echo "============================"
                        echo "${java_output}"
                        echo "============================"
                else
                        echo "$java_base_dir directory found!"
                fi
                ;;

        "Option 3: Reply")

                echo "Reply"
                echo "================================================================"
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                ;;

        "Quit")
                break
                ;;

        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY" ;;
        esac
done
```

Now the question is, I have to select all the options which ever i'm having inside my case, for example (option 1 java installation and option 2 tomcat installation) when i am selecting option 1, java will install and same case when i using option 2 tomcat will install.

Now i want install both software's using the option all.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does _to add all like (*) options_ exactly mean?

Comment: i just updated the query, please help me on this

Comment: This is not really bash-related, but more a general programming question: I would first factor out the code for installing java and installing tomcat into functions or shell scripts, and then add a new _case_, for instance `"Option ALL: Install both)`, and invoke both installation programs from there.

Comment: I agree, you point, now my confusion is how to call the my function(1 and 2) in upcoming new function called "Option 3: Install both)

Comment: In bash, you call two commands by separating them by a semicolon or by a newline. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create functions or scripts for each individual installation and add an option for installing both:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    case $opt in

    "Option 1: Tomcat Installation")
        install_tomcat
        ;;
    "Option 2: Java Installation")
        install_java
        ;;
    "Option GREEDY: Install everything")
        install_tomcat; install_java
        ;;
    ....
```